# java.lang.ClassCastException: com.marklogic.xcc.jndi.ContentSourceBeanFactory cannot be cast to javax.naming.spi.InitialContextFactory]

Tags: java, wso2, marklogic, wso2-data-services-server

Im having an error while creating JNDI datasource in WSO2 Data Services Server, I'm using the MarkLogic XCC/J connector as may JNDI Context Class but i got an error..

```
DS Fault Message: Naming error occurred while trying to retrieve JDBC Connection from JNDI tree. DS Code: UNKNOWN_ERROR Source Data Service:- Name: marklogicserver Location: /marklogicserver.dbs Description: N/A Default Namespace: http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice Nested Exception:- javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Failed to create InitialContext using factory specified in hash table. [Root exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: com.marklogic.xcc.jndi.ContentSourceBeanFactory cannot be cast to javax.naming.spi.InitialContextFactory] at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.description.config.JNDIConfig.createDataSource(JNDIConfig.java:95) at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.description.config.JNDIConfig.(JNDIConfig.java:49) at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.description.config.ConfigFactory.getJNDIConfig(ConfigFactory.java:98) at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.description.config.ConfigFactory.createConfig(ConfigFactory.java:62) at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.DataServiceFactory.createDataService(DataServiceFactory.java:150) at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.DBDeployer.createDBService(DBDeployer.java:785) at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.DBDeployer.processService(DBDeployer.java:1139) at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.DBDeployer.deploy(DBDeployer.java:195) at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.DeploymentFileData.deploy(DeploymentFileData.java:136) at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.doDeploy(DeploymentEngine.java:807) at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.WSInfoList.update(WSInfoList.java:144) at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.update(RepositoryListener.java:377) at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.checkServices(RepositoryListener.java:254) at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.loadServices(DeploymentEngine.java:135) at org.wso2.carbon.core.CarbonAxisConfigurator.deployServices(CarbonAxisConfigurator.java:567)
```

Here is my configuration file

```
<data name="marklogicserver" transports="http https local">
   <config enableOData="false" id="mlsource">
      <property name="jndi_context_class">com.marklogic.xcc.jndi.ContentSourceBeanFactory</property>
      <property name="jndi_provider_url"></property>
      <property name="jndi_resource_name">marklogic/ContentSource</property>
   </config>
   <query id="getQuery" useConfig="mlsource">
      <sql>let $x := cts:search(fn:collection(""),cts:and-query(("","")))&#xd;&#xd;return $x</sql>
      <result element="Documents" rowName="Document">
         <element column="Data" name="Data" xsdType="string"/>
      </result>
   </query>
   <operation name="getQueryOperation">
      <call-query href="getQuery"/>
   </operation>
   <resource method="GET" path="getQuery">
      <call-query href="getQuery"/>
   </resource>
</data>
```

What wrong with my configuration?
Please help

Comment: take a look at this: http://code.lds.org/maven-sites/stack/modules/marklogic/1.2.1/

Comment: it doesnt work for me :(

Answer (score 1):

Looks like WSO2 wants something that implements javax.naming.spi.InitialContextFactory, but the ContentSourceFactoryBean only implements javax.naming.spi.ObjectFactory.

I have not tried this, but I imagine you can write an implementation of InitialContextFactory that produces a Context that will ensure that ContentSourceFactoryBean is used as the ObjectFactory implementation.